# Show that $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is symmetric positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let $A$ be $m\times n$ matrix with full column rank where $m > n$. Let $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$. How do we show that $P$ is SPD (symmetric positive definite)? Proving that it is symmetric is trivial, but how can I show it is positive definite?

Comment: $P$ is never positive definite: it is $m\times m$ but its rank is at most $n$.

Comment: @user1551 Exactly $n$, in fact.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Sure, but that is unimportant here.

Comment: @Ted Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Some facts about positive semi-definite (PSD) matrices:

> 1. If $X$ is any matrix, then $X^\top X$ is always PSD.
> 2. The inverse of an (invertible) PSD matrix is also PSD.
> 3. A matrix $X$ is PSD if and only of $x^\top Xx\ge 0$ for all vectors $x$.

So we try 3. on the matrix $P$:

$$x^\top P x=x^\top A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top x=\underbrace{(A^\top x)^\top}_{y^\top} (A^\top A)^{-1}\underbrace{A^\top x}_{y}=y^\top\underbrace{(A^\top A)^{-1}}_{X}y=y^\top X y\ge 0.$$

The last inequality follows from the fact that $X$ is PSD by 1. and 2. This shows *semi*-definiteness of $P$.  However, it seems $P$ cannot be (strictly) positive definite. Note first, that it is a projection:

$$PP=A(A^\top A)^{-1} \underbrace{A^\top A(A^\top A)^{-1}}_{I} A^\top =P$$

(this might suffice to show that $P$ is positive semi-definite). Further note that

$$Pv=A \underbrace{(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top v}_u=Au \in \mathrm{span}(a_1,..,a_n),$$

where $a_1,...,a_n$ are the columns of $A$. Since the columns space is $m$-dimensional but $\mathrm{span}(a_1,...,a_n)$ is $n$-dimensional with $n<m$, we see that $P$ is a projection onto a proper subspace of $\Bbb R^m$. Hence, there exist a non-zero $v\in\ker(P)$ and $P$ cannot be (strictly) positive definite.

Comment: But isn't it a projection matrix for Col(A)? or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi you're right

Comment: @DF then for $w\perp Col(A) \implies w^TPw=0$?

Comment: @M.Winter ah ok, I agree and maybe by this fact (P projection matrix) it is straighforwad to show semi-definiteness for P.

Comment: @M.Winter thus P is it positive definite? I'm loosing something with $w\perp Col(A)$ for which we should have $w^TPw=0$. Could you please explain this point? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi I am just now understanding that $P$ is a projection. You are right about this. It's strange. Maybe there is a mistake in my reasoning. I will have to think about that.

Comment: I agree with gimusi, it can't be true that $P$ is positive definite. See what happens if $n=1$ for example.

Comment: I think your argument in the last sentence shows that $\ker(A)=\{0\}$, not $\ker(A^T)$.

Comment: You should revise or delete since the answer is uncorrect.

Comment: @gimusi Of course. I was occupied for a while, but fixed it I think. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P$ is an m-by m [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#Ordinary_least_squares) on $Col(A)$ thus for $\vec w\neq \vec 0$ and $\vec w \perp Col(A)$ we have $P\vec w=0$ and $w^TPw=0$.

Thus $P$ is a **semi-positive definite** matrix, indeed $\forall\vec x$ we can write $\vec x=a\vec v+b\vec w$ and since

- for $\vec v\in Col(A) \implies \vec v^TP\vec v=\vec v^T \vec v\ge0$
- for $\vec w\perp Col(A) \implies \vec w^TP \vec w=0$

we have that

- $\vec x^TP\vec x\ge0$ with $\vec x^TP\vec x=0$ for some $\vec x \neq \vec 0$.

Comment: @DF but $m>n$ thus exist $w\neq 0 \perp Col(A)$, am I wrong?

Comment: @yes, I think you're right, sorry

Comment: @Arnaud.D why this edit in the final line? It is not correct I will rollback

Comment: @ArnaudD. What I mean is that $\vec x^TP\vec x\geq 0$ with $\vec x^TP\vec x= 0$ for some $\vec x \neq \vec 0$. Alfo for a positive definite matrix we have that $\vec x^TP\vec x\geq 0$ but $\vec x^TP\vec x = 0\iff \vec x=0$

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Sorry for the wrong edit then.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetry: 
$$(A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)^T=(A^T)^T((A^TA)^{-1})^TA^T=A(((A^TA)^T)^{-1}A^T=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

Positive semidefinite:

$$\langle A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx,x\rangle=\langle(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx,A^Tx\rangle=\langle(A^TA)^{-1}y,y\rangle$$
where $y:=A^Tx$, also $A^TA$ is invertible since $A$ has full column rank so $(A^TA)^{-1}$ exists and makes sense. Using $(A^TA)^{-1}y:=z$ then $y=A^TAz$ so finally we have
$$\langle(A^TA)^{-1}y,y\rangle=\langle z,A^TAz\rangle=\langle Az,Az\rangle=||Az||^2\geqslant 0$$
as required.